# Maximum number of Licences Issued in year 2017 to different categories

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to find the Maximum number of Licences Issued in the year 2017 for different categories. Please help

```
SELECT
    YEAR(BL.[Issued]) as YearIssuesd,
    BL.[Category] as Category, 
    COUNT(*) as TotalLicenceIssued 
from
    [dbo].[businesslicences$] BL 
GROUP BY
    YEAR(BL.[Issued]),
    (BL.[Category])
HAVING
    COUNT(*) = (
        SELECT
            MAX(MC)
        FROM
        (
            SELECT
                COUNT( BL.[Licence No#] ) AS MC
            from
                [dbo].[businesslicences$] BL
            GROUP BY BL.[Category]
        )
```

Comment: It looks like you're just wanting the **total number** issued (per category, per year). What do you mean by "maximum number for different categories" though?

Comment: What is the `CREATE TABLE` statement for `dbo.businesslicenses$`? Why is there a dollar-symbol in the table name?

Comment: $ symbol is there because Database name and table name is same

Comment: That's not what `$` is for though (see https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/193574/what-is-the-significance-of-the-trailing-dollar-sign-on-identifiers-in-sql-s ) because it's escaped in square-brackets, so it's taken literally - and it doesn't matter if the name is the same unless there's ambiguity.

Comment: If my answer isn't what you're after then your question is too unclear. Please post your input data and **a sample of expected output data**.

Comment: -- #2 KPI: Maximum No. of Licences issued per category per year from 2016 to 2018
SELECT YEAR(BL.[Issued]) as YearIssuesd, BL.[Category] as Category, 
COUNT(BL.[Licence No#]) as TotalLicenceIssued from [dbo].[businesslicences$] BL 
WHERE YEAR(BL.[Issued])>=2016 AND YEAR(BL.[Issued])>=2018
GROUP BY YEAR(BL.[Issued]), (BL.[Category])
ORDER BY COUNT(BL.[Licence No#]) DESC

Comment: This query works but i am unable to use the MAX function. I want to find the category which is having max no.of  licences issued

Comment: In other words, i want Category per year from 2016 to 2018 having max no. of licences issued. But the values in the [Licence No#] is a varchar so I am unable to apply aggregate function

Comment: Expected Outcome                                                                                                    [Year] [Category Having maximum licences issued] [Licence Count]
2016 A 3452
2017 B 345
2018 D 7876

Comment: To confirm, you want the **single category** with the most licenses **for every year**?

Comment: The term "maximum" has specific connotations when working data, you should have used the term **modal** instead.

Answer (score 0):

> Maximum number of Licences Issued in year 2017 to different categories

> I want to find the Maximum number of Licences Issued in the year 2017 for different categories.

You've written very little and provided no examples of source table data and expected output data. But I'm inferring that you want something like this?

```
SELECT
    YEAR( bl.Issued ) AS YearIssued, /* This will always be '2017' due to the WHERE clause */
    bl.Category,
    COUNT(*) AS Number_of_licenses_issued_this_year_in_this_category
FROM
    dbo.[BusinessLicenses$] AS bl
WHERE
    YEAR( bl.Issued ) = 2017
GROUP BY
    YEAR( bl.Issued ),
    bl.Category
```

To get the **single maximum** use `TOP 1 ... ORDER BY Number_of_licenses_issued_this_year_in_this_category DESC`:

```
SELECT
    TOP 1

    YEAR( bl.Issued ) AS YearIssued, /* This will always be '2017' */
    bl.Category,
    COUNT(*) AS Number_of_licenses_issued_this_year_in_this_category
FROM
    dbo.[BusinessLicenses$] AS bl
WHERE
    YEAR( bl.Issued ) = 2017
GROUP BY
    YEAR( bl.Issued ),
    bl.Category
ORDER BY
    Number_of_licenses_issued_this_year_in_this_category DESC
```

But it's meaningless to ask for "Maximum number of Licences Issued in the year 2017 for different categories" because the "maximum number of X" requires X to be a set of values, but in the query you posted X is just a scalar (the result of `COUNT(*)`).

Comment: i want Max no. of  licences issued per category per year

Comment: @AnkitSharma I don't think you're using terminology correctly when you say "max per category per year". Do you understand why I said that's a meaningless statement? **There is no maximum** because there's only a **scalar value** per category per year.

Comment: I want to derive a KPI for my database. Where I have to implement Aggregate functions like MAX, AVG on the count of Licence numbers

Answer (score 0):

> In other words, i want Category per year from 2016 to 2018 having max no. of licences issued. But the values in the [Licence No#] is a varchar so I am unable to apply aggregate function

> Expected Outcome
>
> | Year | Category | License Count |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 2016 | A | 3452 |
> | 2017 | B | 345 |
> | 2018 | D | 7876 |

You'll need a CTE or inner-query to compute the `COUNT` values *first*, and then find the modal category in the outer query:

```
WITH licensesPerCategoryPerYear AS (

    SELECT
        YEAR( bl.Issued ) AS [Year],
        bl.Category,
        COUNT(*) AS [Count]
    FROM
        dbo.[BusinessLicenses$] AS bl
    GROUP BY
        YEAR( bl.Issued ),
        bl.Category
)
WITH modalCategoryPerYear AS (
    
    SELECT
        [Year],
        MAX( [Count] ) AS MaxCountInYear
    FROM
        licensesPerCategoryPerYear
    GROUP BY
        [Year]
)

SELECT
    mcy.[Year],
    lcy.Category AS [Category having most licenses issued],
    lcy.[Count]
FROM
    modalCategoryPerYear AS mcy
    INNER JOIN licensesPerCategoryPerYear AS lcy ON
        lcy .[Year] = mcy.[Year]
        AND
        lcy .[Count] = mcy.MaxCountInYear

ORDER BY
    mcy.[Year]
```